# Removing Hose Attachment on Kohler Kitchen Faucet

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I'm not sure how exactly to remove this attachement, and I don't want to break anything. Anyone have any ideas. I've checked a bunch of youtube videos for similiar faucets with no luck.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second pic, the white clip at the top appears to be the release.  I can see an O-ring inside (through the plastic) just below that level, so release the clip and you should be able to pull the white plastic part down.